# licenses <-> licensing tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is a tag "licenses" that had only 4 questions assigned. There is a tag "licensing" that had 16 questions assigned. I have re-tagged questions with "lisenses" to "licensing" not to have two many similar tags. How can I remove "licenses" tag? Or can somebody remove that now not used tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the tag has no questions on it, it will be removed by the system over time IIRC. There are no controls to delete a tag.

You might want to suggest a tag synonym to point `licenses` to `licensing`.